# Resources for game networking in Java

Tags: java, networking, multiplayer

I am currently working on a Java multiplayer game. The game itself (single player) already works perfectly fine and so does the chat. The only thing that is really missing is the multiplayer part. Sadly I am absolutely clueless on where to start with that. I roughly know that I will have to work with packages, and I also know many things about streaming etc (chat is already working). Oh and it should - according to this article - be a UDP server. My problem is that I can't find any resources on how to do this. A tutorial (book or website) would be perfect, alternatively a good example of an open source client/server (in Java of course) would be fine as well. If you feel like doing something helpful I'd also really appreciate someone "privately" teaching me via email or some chat program :)

Thank you!

Comment: Cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435998/resources-for-game-networking

Comment: UDP vs. TCP: whether you use one, the other or both depends entirely on the game; there is no blanket statement possible.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider looking at the [RedDwarf project](http://www.reddwarfserver.org/?q=content/open-source-online-gaming-universe) that has been a community fork of [Project Darkstar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Darkstar). The latter was a Research Project at Sun Microsystems and discontinued after Oracle took it over.

It was developed to be a horizontably scalable middleware and seems to have been very popular. The source of the RedDwarf Server fork is available on Sourceforge. That gave me an idea of how the serverside of a game can be realized. The documentation sometimes lacks information about the intentions of some classes but it gave me a basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Netty](http://netty.io/) - it's a very good high performance networking library that is well suited for game development. It has some very good documentation and tutorials.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146587/nettys-suitability-as-a-game-server